# Merge data frames based on date

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I want to merge 2 data frames.

The first data frame looks like:

```
Date    Value
1968-04-01  38.0
1968-04-02  37.6
1968-04-03  37.7
1968-04-04  36.7
1968-04-05  37.2
1968-04-08  37.0
1968-04-09  37.25
1968-04-10  37.6
```

The second data frame looks like:

```
1991-06-21  4.44
1991-06-22  4.39
1991-06-24  4.39
1991-06-25  4.37
1991-06-26  4.41
1991-06-27  4.36
```

Both data sets go up to present day.

How do I create a new dataframe that starts the data in 1991 since that is where the second data set starts? And has a column for each price.

I tried:

```
df_all_rows = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

but this just puts one set of data below the other one.

I guess currently the data does not go up to present day. But how can I just create a new dataframe with only dates that both series have?

Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import quandl
from datetime import datetime

df1=quandl.get("BUNDESBANK/BBK01_WT5511", authtoken="6F92X3NEV8DdrhAc_d5_")
df2=quandl.get("PERTH/SLVR_USD_D", authtoken="6F92X3NEV8DdrhAc_d5_")
df2=df2.dropna()

T1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=df1.index, how='inner')
```

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I think I asked the question above, not sure what you mean.

Comment: You outlined the goal or objective, not a specific problem or obstacle.

Comment: do you want all the data from both dataframes or just the ones with the same date?

Comment: Just the ones with the same date

Comment: Just updated my question with the code I have right now, but as you can see, it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
import pandas as pd
merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

you can change the way you merge with the `how` parameter. See for more information on joining [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Comment: I tried this, changing T1 and T2 to df1 and df2 so it matches what I had, and it gave me the error:

KeyError: DatetimeIndex(['1968-04-01', '1968-04-02', '1968-04-03', '1968-04-04',
               '1968-04-05', '1968-04-08', '1968-04-09', '1968-04-10',
               '1968-04-11', '1968-04-16',
               ...
               '2016-04-05', '2016-04-06', '2016-04-07', '2016-04-08',
               '2016-04-11', '2016-04-12', '2016-04-13', '2016-04-14',
               '2016-04-15', '2016-04-18'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=12152, freq=None)

Comment: hm, try setting both the indexes in the merge by: `merge=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: I will try this, I just added my code to the question so you can see what is going on